# Redirecionar Http para Https - Nginx com let's encrypt

Tags: python, django, criptografia, nginx, https

No momento, o domino https://meudominio.com está funcionando, mas não consigo redirecionar *http* para *https* utilizando o *let's encrypt*.

Estou seguindo este tutorial: [Link](https://pythonprogramming.net/django-web-server-https-lets-encrypt-ssl/)

Abaixo a minha configuração:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name meudominio.com www.meudominio.com;


    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/meudominio.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/meudominio.com/privkey.pem;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/project/user;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/project/user/meudominio.sock;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name meudominio.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Porquê utilizar dois blocos `server` com a mesma porta?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Eu faço isto de outra forma:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name meudominio.com;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$host/$1 permanent;
}
```

acredito que se você quiser fazer desta forma acho que deveria ser assim:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name meudominio.com;

    location ~ (.*)$ {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Teste ai de nos dê um feedback.

Comment: Sim é isso mesmo, já havia solucionado o problema. Muito obrigado.!